# Signature of quantum phase transition in sudden quench

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, ising-model

Let's say I have a system which undergoes a phase transition, if a parameter $g$ of system is greater than some $g_{c}$.  Suppose if the system is in normal phase $(g < g_{c})$ and I suddenly quench the Hamiltonian at some instant $t=t_{0}$ to somewhere $g>g_{c}$, what property can I immediately to look at $t=t_{0}$ (which is also experimentally measurable) to know that I crossed the phase transition critical point $g_{c}$. Most of my findings direct me to Loschmidt echo which is primarily an indicator of dynamical quantum phase transitions (DQPT).  But I am not interested in DQPT, any help or insight would help.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, there is nothing you can look at directly at $t = t_0$ to indicate a phase transition. Unitary evolution is continuous; immediately changing your time-evolution operator from $e^{-i H_1 t}$ for $t < t_0$ to $e^{-i H_2 t}$ for $t \geq t_0$ will not discontinuously change the state of your system. For example, if your quench experiment initially has the system in the ground state of $H_1$, then when you quench to $H_2$ at $t=t_0$, the instantaneous state of the system at $t_0$ is still the ground state of $H_1$. All the interesting features of a quench happen in the time following $t_0$.

Comment: then, at later times $(t>t_{0})$, in general what can i compute to know that i crossed $g>g_{c}$?

Comment: Your question is too general. Clearly there are lots of things you can compute to determine whether your system is quenched into a different phase. But it's hard to say specifically without a Hamiltonian in mind.

Comment: Suppose say in 1D transverse Ising model, what can i do to know that I crossed $g>g_c$?